# How are doReturn and toReturn different in Mockito?

Tags: mockito

Is there any difference between these two lines of code?

***Option 1:***

```
doReturn(masterQuery).when(tldSpy).makeMyInsightAPIQuery(anyString());
```

***Option 2:***

```
stub(tldSpy.makeMyInsightAPIQuery(anyString())).toReturn(masterQuery);
```

Someone else asked a similar question ([Mockito - difference between doReturn() and when()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353846/mockito-difference-between-doreturn-and-when)) but I'm asking about `toReturn()` which was not addressed in that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`stub(T).toReturn(...)`](http://mockito.github.io/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#stub(T)) is just a [deprecated syntax](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/master/src/org/mockito/Mockito.java#L1425) replaced by `when(T).thenReturn(...)`. Same rules and guidelines apply as in [the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353846/mockito-difference-between-doreturn-and-when):

- `when().thenReturn()` and `stub().toReturn()` can do return type checking
- `doAnswer().when()` is the only way to stub void methods
- `doReturn().when()` [avoids calling the real method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26190394/1426891) in spies and already-stubbed objects

Otherwise, they have exactly the same behavior and the same consequences, and can be used interchangeably.